# Lag in CSS3 animation

Tags: html, css, slideshow

Alright, I am trying to make a pure CSS3 image slideshow. (Yes, I know it could be done with JQuery easier.) I cannot get it to work on my browser, chrome, so I have not yet added the syntax for the other browsers.

My HTML is...

```
            <div class="slide-show">
                <img src="pictures/slide-1.jpg" alt="Broken Earth" class="slide-1"/>
                <img src="pictures/slide-2.jpg" alt="World Map" class="slide-2"/>
                <img src="pictures/slide-3.jpg" alt="Sunset" class="slide-3"/>
                <img src="pictures/slide-4.jpg" alt="Ursumian Flag" class="slide-4"/>
            </div>
```

And my CSS is...

```
.slide-show {

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #746d27;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 30px;

}

.slide-1 {

    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: one;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;

}

.slide-2 {

    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: two;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;

}

.slide-3 {

    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: three;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;

}

.slide-4 {

    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: four;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;

}

@-webkit-keyframes one {

    0%   {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    15%  {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    20%  {left: 600px; top: 0px;}
    21%  {left: 600px; top: 300px;}
    22%  {left: -600px; top: 300px;}
    23%  {left: -600px; top: 0px;}
    95%  {left: -600px; top: 0px;}
    100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes two {

    0%   {left: -600px; top: -305px;}
    15%   {left: -600px; top: -305px;}
    20%   {left: 0px; top: -305px;}
    35%   {left: 0px; top: -305px;}
    40%   {left: 600px; top: -305px;}
    41%   {left: 600px; top: -5px;}
    42%   {left: -600px; top: -5px;}
    43%   {left: -600px; top: -305px;}
    100%   {left: -600px; top: -305px;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes three {

    0%   {left: -600px; top: -610px;}
    35%   {left: -600px; top: -610px;}
    40%   {left: 0px; top: -610px;}
    55%   {left: 0px; top: -610px;}
    60%   {left: 600px; top: -610px;}
    61%   {left: 600px; top: -310px;}
    62%   {left: -600px; top: -310px;}
    63%   {left: -600px; top: -610px;}
    100%   {left: -600px; top: -610px;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes four {

    0%   {left: -600px; top: -915px;}
    55%   {left: -600px; top: -915px;}
    60%   {left: 0px; top: -915px;}
    75%   {left: 0px; top: -915px;}
    80%   {left: 600px; top: -915px;}
    81%   {left: 600px; top: -615px;}
    82%   {left: -600px; top: -615px;}
    83%   {left: -600px; top: -915px;}
    100%   {left: -600px; top: -915px;}

}
```

Notice, the "slide-show" class does have "overflow" set to "visible." This is so I can make sure all the images are shifting properly. When they do, that will be switched to "hidden." There are 4 pictures, and each should only be moving in/out of the stage for 2 seconds total, and each should spend 3 seconds total sitting in the stage. Why do I have a lag in the last slide?

Comment: Can you add a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Don't only use -webkit-, add another one for every 'style' without the -webkit-

Also, can you provide a demo?

Comment: http://testportfolio.bugs3.com/

Put it on a test server. I know about the "-webkit-" thing. I am just trying to get it work before I add a whole bunch more code and make it all the more confusing.

Comment: It doesn't lag on mine, which part should i see the lag?

Comment: The first slide does not return to it's original position in time. I have the timing wrong somehow. It is supposed to be a seamless loop of pictures.

Comment: it does actually lag sometimes very strange

Comment: This *might* be due to javascripts garbage collection kicking in. I know this is vague but I think that the memory has to be released at a better time so that the garbage collector does not activate mid way.